# Get string up to character using regex

Tags: php, regex

These are examples of my strings:

```
My title - K21
Some title  - G-21
Title something - M-02
```

I need to strip the code and the hyphen so I get clear title.

```
My title
Some title
Title something
```

This is the code I came up so far, but it gives me G-21 as result, and I need the opposite, I need a result of regular expression.

```
$string = 'Some title - G-21';
$pattern = '/.+? (?=&#8211;)/i'; // this is ok, &#8211 is for '-'
echo preg_replace($pattern, '', $string);
```

Comment: Is the code ALWAYS present? Can there be more than one space-hyphen-space in the file?

Comment: Code is currently present, I am not sure if it will be like this. Also for title, everything is possible :D

Comment: Either use `preg_replace` with [`\h*-\h*\S+$`](https://regex101.com/r/uH4hF9/3), or use `preg_match` with [`^(.*?) +-`](https://regex101.com/r/uH4hF9/2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have to use a regular expressions?

```
<?php
$str = 'Some title  - G-21';
$res = trim(array_shift(explode("&#8211;", $str, 2)));

echo $res;
?>
```

Comment: If there are more than one space-hyphen-space, it won't work. See https://ideone.com/3PTRz6

Answer (score 1):

Use the following regex pattern for multiple substrings:

```
$str = "My title - K21
Some title  - G-21
Title something - M-02";

$result = preg_replace("/-\s+[A-Z]-?\d+/", "", $str);

print_r($result);
```

The output:

```
My title 
Some title  
Title something
```

Comment: I wonder why you chose `\b`? It seems the code is at the end of the string and `$` looks more appropriate. Also, why do you tend to use `{1,}` instead of a `+`? And one more: `-\s+?[A-Z]` = `-\s+[A-Z]`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, as for `\b` - agreed, as for `{1,}` - used just as an alternative to `+`. But, why ungready opearator is redundant in this `\s+?` case on your opinion?

Comment: There will be no difference in behavior here between `\s+?` and `\s+`. What difference did you expect?

Comment: in such simple case, perhaps, yes ... At the end of the working day, I've missed that things. Fixed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to look at this one. The first direct answer to your question is to use [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) instead of preg_replace.

The second way to look at it is to use your current preg_replace syntax to strip off the end of the strings. Something like `/\s+-.+$/` should work for stripping off the hyphen and everything after it